# I want to join object inside state with prop

Tags: reactjs, object, get, use-state, react-props

I have objects key and value in state if I want to get date i used {key.value} but objects is located as such as
{
name1: "Hello",
name2: "World",
}
I have some index is coming with prop value as number as dynamic
How i get this value as dynamic. such as {name + {index}} === name1
It should shows like that

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, this is your object:

```
 const testObject = {
    [`name${index}`]:name1
  }
```